# Undefined reference in an object file - how find which library contains it?

Tags: c++, c, linker

I have successfully compiled openssl library with Windows mingw... Then I'm linking it with my application, but it fails with unresolved symbol `_imp__shutdown`. The `nm` tells the object file really references the symbol.

How can one find out which library should be added to `ld` to resolve that dependency? Is there a standard procedure for such cases?

Linking:

```
> g++ -static -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition -mthreads -Wl,-subsystem,windows ... -lws2_32 -lshlwapi ... -lssl -lcrypto ...

C:/openssl-1.0.1g-mgw\libcrypto.a(bss_sock.o):bss_sock.c:(.text+0x90): undefined reference to `_imp__shutdown@8'
C:/openssl-1.0.1g-mgw\libcrypto.a(bss_sock.o):bss_sock.c:(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `_imp__shutdown@8'
c:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/openssl-1.0.1g-mgw\libcrypto.a(bss_sock.o): bad reloc address 0x4 in section `.data'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The unresolved symbol:

```
> nm /c/openssl-1.0.1g-mgw/crypto/bio/bss_sock.o
            ...
            U __imp__closesocket@4
            U __imp__recv@16
            U __imp__send@16
            U __imp__shutdown@8
            U __imp__WSAGetLastError@0
            U __imp__WSASetLastError@4
            ...
```

GCC / Windows 7 x64:

```
> g++ --version
g++.exe (i686-posix-dwarf-rev3, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.8.2
```

Comment: The documentation of the `shutdown()` function should tell you which library to link with.

Comment: This looks like it may be a name mangling issue. Do you have the declaration of `shutdown()` in `extern "C"`?

Comment: Given the names of the other symbols, this is likely the function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740481.aspx

Comment: `_imp__shutdown@8` != `__imp__shutdown@8`

Comment: Looks like the function belongs to `libws2_32.a` (linked already), but the underscores really differs :-|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are doing static linking with gcc, you need to provide the libraries in reverse order of dependencies. If needed to resolve circular dependencies, you must provide the library names several times on the command line (e.g. if libfoo depends on libbar and libbar depends on libfoo, do -lfoo -lbar -lfoo)

In this case, since `-lssl` depends on these socket functions that are defined in the `ws2_32` library, add `-lws2_32` after `-lssl`

And to answer the actual question you pose, if you want to find which library provides a function, go to the documentation for that function ,e.g. the [shutdown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740481(v=vs.85).aspx) function documents that you need to link to `Ws2_32.lib`

Comment: You saved me! My app builds fine after this change.